# Dont print secrets in log

Tags: arrays, string, logging, go, substring

I am using [Zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) logger and I want to limit the information that gets logged. For example , I have below code snippet

```
func (m *mountCommand) Execute(args []string) error {

    filelogger.Info("First log", zap.Strings("input args", args))
```

And the log output is as below

```
    {"level":"info","ts":"2017-11-16T10:04:40.225Z","msg":"First log","input args":["/var/lib/kubelet/pods/74785895-cab5-11e7-88ed-ce1c8b57856c/volumes/xyz-xandndnd",
    "{\"kubernetes.io/secret/access-key\":\"Qdfnnfbbdnsjnxni8ehh=\",\"kubernetes.io/secret/secret-key\":\"GGHNHwsffUIJMNBNBVV==\",
\"parallel-count\":\"5\",\"region\":\"iam-standard\"}"]}
```

How do I just prevent the access-key and secret-key values from getting added to the log due to sensitivity of the data.

I tried many string manipulation functions in Go so that I can just remove those contents before using the zap object.There seems no simple function to get this done in a straight forward simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current `args` is a slice of the following `string`s:

```
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/74785895-cab5-11e7-88ed-ce1c8b57856c/volumes/xyz-xandndnd
{"kubernetes.io/secret/access-key":"Qdfnnfbbdnsjnxni8ehh=","kubernetes.io/secret/secret-key":"GGHNHwsffUIJMNBNBVV==","parallel-count":"5","region":"iam-standard"}
```

The input argument that contains the security-sensitive data is at index `1`, and it's a JSON text.

You should not "string-manipulate" a JSON text. First you should unmarshal it into a Go value, then manipulate it, then marshal it back.

This is how this can be done:

```
// Make a copy of args:
args2 := append([]string{}, args...)

// Unmarshal:
var m map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(args2[1]), &m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Modify:
m["kubernetes.io/secret/access-key"] = "XXX"
m["kubernetes.io/secret/secret-key"] = "YYY"

// Marshal:
s2, err := json.Marshal(m)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
args2[1] = string(s2)

// Verify:
fmt.Println(args2[1])

// Now use args2 to log
filelogger.Info("First log", zap.Strings("(masked) input args", args2))
```

The "Verify:" is obviously not needed, it's just for us to see the result. Output on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hZPRlv-vMR):

```
{"kubernetes.io/secret/access-key":"XXX","kubernetes.io/secret/secret-key":"YYY","parallel-count":"5","region":"iam-standard"}
```

In your solution you should also add slice index checks to avoid run-time panic.